# Schmidt decomposition with no local inner-products.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, gram-schmidt

Assume I have a pair of finite-dimensional vector spaces $V_A$ and $V_B$, and let $\mathcal{H}$
be their tensor-product space:
$$
\mathcal{H}=V_A\otimes V_B.
$$
Let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ be an inner-product on $\mathcal{H}$.

My question is as follows:
Do we have a Schmidt decomposition for any $v\in \mathcal{H}$.
i.e. can we always have a representation
$$
v=\sum_i \lambda_i \phi_i \otimes \psi_i ,
$$
where $\{\phi_i \otimes \psi_i\}_i\subset \mathcal{H}$ is an orthonormal set and $\lambda_i>0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i^2=1$?

In particular, does any inner-product allows
an orthonormal basis of product vectors?